# Object name from String in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

i want to set the name of an object like UIButton from a string.

`NSString *buttonName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"someString"];`

My goal is:

`UIButton *someString = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]retain];`

how can i solve this?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense... your first code sample isn't even valid Objective-C, and it is not really clear what your intention is. A UIButton is no string. Please be more verbose, explain your problem that you want to solve with this "setting name of an object".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't - variable names are resolved by the compiler well before any Objective-C code is executed. What you *can* do is maintain a map of strings to objects like buttons etc. using `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
NSString *string = @"someString";
[buttonMap setObject: [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] forKey: string];

//...time passes...

[[buttonMap objectForKey: @"someString"] setEnabled: YES];
```