# Creating pointer names programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, pointers, for-loop

I'm creating this loop, and as you can see, there is a problem: you can't initialize a variable-sized object in this kind of situation. How would I set the loop up so that it creates pointer names for the `UITouch` unique, without an array, for example if there are 3 touches, the loop would create three separate `UITouch` pointers, `touch1`, `touch2`, and `touch3`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= touchCount; i++) {

    UITouch *touch[i] = [touchArray objectAtIndex:i-1];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object name from String in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888935/object-name-from-string-in-objective-c)

Comment: Simple answer is you can't. What do you need the touches for. That might help us give you the proper answer.

Comment: If the scope of the objects are only inside the for loop, What is the need for giving them different names?

Comment: I am not seeing why a "unique name" is needed. What is wrong with an array of n (3 in this case) elements?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164134/object-with-the-name-of-a-string

Comment: The scope of the objects are not just inside the loop]

Comment: @Conor Taylor, But you are creating the objects inside the for loop, isn't it? How do you think you can use those objects outside the loop? :-) I guess there is little confusion in what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is unnecessary since you already have pointers to your touches stored in touchArray. If you want to explicitly create distinct object for each touch you have to create them manually.

Or you could do a little trick like this:

//Create a method named touchNumbered:(int)number

```
-(UITouch*)touchNumbered:(int)number{
   return [touchArray objectAtIndex:number];
}
```

It all depends on what you want to do with those touches.