# Objective-C identifier from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I want to pass an NSString to a method and have that particular NSString name a new NSSMutableArray. Confusing? Programmatically looks like this:

```
+ (void)newMutableArrayWithName:(NSString*)theArrayName
{
     NSLog(@"Creating an array that is named: %@",theArrayName);
     NSMutableArray* theArrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Unfortunately, "theArrayName" is not affiliated with the argument passed to the method. Is there any way this is achievable?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Even in languages where this is possible, chances are, if you think you want to dynamically name a variable, you're doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: @sidyll For an example have an array that contains "everythingOnMyDesk" and create new arrays for each item from "everythingOnMyDesk". So if I have an "apple" and a "pen" it will store it in "everythingOnMyDesk" and will have new arrays called "apple" and "pen".

Comment: Does it really matter _why_ a question is asked? Just answer it if you can. The user might have a very good reason for asking. I'd love to be able to do this for debugging!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object name from String in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888935/object-name-from-string-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of a variable is used by the compiler, and is set at compile-time, not at run time.

If you need to be able to associate a label with an array, I suggest that you use an NSDictionary to do something like this

```
NSString *theArrayName = @"My Cool Array";
NSMutableArray *theArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDictionary *theDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                                      theArray, theArrayName, nil];
```

You could have multiple "named" arrays in the dictionary, if you wanted, and could access them by the names that you gave them

```
[theDictionary objectForKey:@"My Cool Array"];
```

Comment: My favorite way of doing this is `NSMutableDictionary* myDict; [myDict setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object1",@"Object2",nil] forKey:@"My Array Name!"];`

Answer (score 2):

Look into [key-value coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE) for setting the values of existing properties by the property's name, but it appears it can't create a new property.  For that, you should just use a dictionary.