# How to Call an Instance Method From a Variable Name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, instance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [object with the name of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164134/object-with-the-name-of-a-string)

I want to call the code below, but be able to change "itemInstance" with a stringe variable. Is this possible?

```
UIImage *image = [itemInstance getImage:itemNumber];
```

EDIT: I just read about the NSSelectorFromString method which appears to be what I need to use, but I have no idea how it's supposed to implemented. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [object with the name of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164134/), [Object name from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888935/)

Comment: @Caleb, I said what I was trying to accomplish in my first sentence... Phillip answered the question. Josh, yes, those do appear to be similar. I didn't see those before. However, I think that the question is still helpful because it is slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly.  The simplest way to get that effect is to build a NSDictionary with your strings as the keys and the matching instances as the values.  Then it becomes something like:

```
UIImage *image = [[dict objectForKey:instanceName] getImage:itemNumber];
```

Comment: Could I use an NSArray instead? I'm going to try that now...

Comment: If you can identify the instance in an array, I guess.  I picked a dictionary because you said you wanted to select by string.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by selecting the instance from an NSArray. I am selecting Phillips answer though because it got me to where I needed to get.